# How to create a backend Grafana plugin for annotations?

Tags: grafana

I understand how to use Grafana's Hashicorp Go-plugin system in order to create a generic time-series datasource plugin.

How can I make a backend plugin that could be used for annotations? The only official example provided is using fake-json-datasource for annotations which is a separate service and not a plugin.

I've found an example of built-in datasource that's providing annotations - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/pkg/tsdb/stackdriver/stackdriver.go#L78-L79. However I'm not sure how to make Grafana do annotations queries to a backend plugin which is not built-in.

Comment: I guess I need to modify this part and make it do requests to my backend plugin instead of an external URL configured - https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-backend-datasource/blob/master/src/datasource.ts#L76-L97. Not sure how.